# Adding carousel slider to woocommerce shop page (not single product page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add carrousel slider for product gallery in woocommerce shop page. I found many plugins and solution for single product page but none of them for the products archive(shop) page.

How can i do that? With plugins or without plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use a plugin to generate a slider ([Product slider for woocommerce](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-slider/)) then you copy the generated shortcode and paste it into your shop page.